# How do you delete an approved promotion?

Tags: sitecore-commerce

Using Sitecore Commerce 8.2.1, I am not able to delete an approved promotion in the Pricing & Promotion Manager. I get the following error message:

> 'MyOrg_PromotionBook-Test Promo' cannot be edited or deleted because it is approved.

This particular promotion was disabled and now we can't re-enable it, edit it, or delete it. We also can't create a new promotion that uses the same coupon code. Nowhere in the documentation (that I have found) does it discuss modifying or deleting promotions.

I have also used Postman to get the entity master view directly and I can see that the Edit, Retract, etc. actions are coming back in the JSON with `"IsEnabled": false`. This tells me that it is not a permissions or UI thing, but a business rule within Commerce Engine.

Comment: The problem is, there could be references to this promotion code. It could be attached to orders and so on - and (as far as I can tell), Sitecore Commerce does not understand the concept of copying entities - so it stores it as a direct reference. Hence it cannot chance. Short of deleting the entity directly (which can be done, the above caveat in mind) - you're stuck with it. You should - obviously - be allowed to create a NEW promotion code with the same code as long as only one is active - this I believe to be a bug.

Comment: As @MarkCassidy said it could be related to another object that is why they don't let you delete it after it is approved and it makes sense. Now, if you think it is not related to any other object (or you don't care) what I've done in this case is deleting it from the `SitecoreCommerce_SharedEnvironments` database (`CommerceEntities` and `CommerceLists` tables)